# SAS bar graph measuring percentage for different variables (one variable measured on y axis and the other shown by shading within the bars)

Tags: graph, sas, grouping, bar-chart, percentage

I have asked this question before but haven't found an answer yet. I am trying to create a bar group in SAS which shows the percentage of patients that received a test by category and within in bar, show the location where the tests were received (location). My dataset looks like this:

```
Category            Test        Test_location
High Risk           1           Site 1
Intermediate Risk   1           Site 2
Low Risk            0           .
Intermediate Risk   0           .
High Risk           1           Site 3
```

Where each patient is listed with the risk classification they have been assigned to (variable 'Category'), an indicator variable that shows whether or not they received a test (variable 'test' where '1'=received test and '0'=did not receive test) and, if they received a test, where that test took place (variable 'test_location').

I want to create a bar graph with the categories on the x axis and the yaxis showing the percentage of patients who got a test (test=1), and then each bar shaded to show the composition of patients who got a test in each category for location (ie: how many tests occurred in Site 1, 2 and 3).

I have the below code, but it is not giving me the percentages that I want. It gives me a pct_col output of test*category, and I want pct_row. In other words, I want the y axis to measure the percentage of patients with testing out of the total number of patients in each category, not out of all patients who receiving testing in any category like it is giving me.

Example of what I want: In the dummy dataset below, for high risk patients, for example, I want a bar that shows 75% (12 patients with tests out of the total 16 high risk patients) received tests, and then have the bar shaded to show 41.66% of those test were at Site 1, 33.34% at Site 2 and 25% at Site 3. And so on for the intermediate and low risk categories. If there is a way to label the subsections with the exact percentages, that would be great too.

Dummy data set:

```
data test;
infile datalines missover;
   input ID Category $ Test Test_location $;
   datalines;
1 High 1 Site_1
2 High 1 Site_1
3 High 1 Site_1
4 High 1 Site_1
5 High 1 Site_1
6 High 1 Site_2
7 High 1 Site_2
8 High 1 Site_2
9 High 1 Site_2
10 High 1 Site_3
11 High 1 Site_3
12 High 1 Site_3
13 High 0
14 High 0
15 High 0
16 High 0
17 Intermediate 1 Site_1
18 Intermediate 1 Site_1
19 Intermediate 1 Site_2
20 Intermediate 0
21 Intermediate 0
22 Intermediate 0
23 Intermediate 0
24 Intermediate 0
25 Intermediate 0
26 Low 1 Site_1
27 Low 1 Site_1
28 Low 1 Site_1
29 Low 1 Site_2
30 Low 1 Site_2
31 Low 1 Site_2
32 Low 1 Site_3
33 Low 0
34 Low 0
35 Low 0
36 Low 0
37 Low 0
38 Low 0
;
```

Thank you!

EDIT;

Here is a sample graph of what I am looking to output in SAS (using the dummy data above):
[image]

Using this code:

```
proc sgplot data=test pctlevel=graph;
    vbar category / response=test stat=percent
        group=test_location groupdisplay=stack datalabel;
    keylegend /title="Testing Location" position=bottom;
quit;
```

I get this output:
[image]

So what I have is not giving my the correct denominators for my percents. I also couldn't figure out a way to label the individual subsections of the graph like I have in my sample figure.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post a sample image of the sort of chart you are trying to create.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post. I am a new user so I cannot post images yet (I need at least 10 reputation points). Give me a vote to get me to ten and I'll gladly post an image!

Comment: You should be able to post an image now.

Comment: Are you having problems with a specific bit of chart-producing code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: See my edits for the code I used and what I'm outputting. What I'm having trouble with is getting it to display the correct percent stat. What I'm getting is the percent of patients in each category to get tests out of only those patients who got tests. I want to show the percent of patients who got tests in each category out of all patients (both those who received tests and those who did not) in each category.

Comment: I would also like to be able to display datalabels on the subsections of the bar to show the percent of patients in each category to receive tests in each of the three sites.

Comment: I strongly recommend taking a look at Robert Allison's site.  I believe he works for SAS basically doing QA on their graphing products.  You can find a list of a huge number of charts here: http://robslink.com/SAS/Home.htm .  I just clicked through a few of those links and found an example bar chart that should show you how to do the labels.  Each chart on the site shows the code and output and is runnable on any SAS installation as long as the correct license is in place.  Check this out: http://robslink.com/SAS/democd26/mekko2_info.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get exactly what you want by using a bit of data step and some formatting. It would be a little bit different from your working code. As others have pointed out, there are many useful examples at [Robert Allison's site.](http://robslink.com/SAS/Home.htm)

I'd go with the simple solution below, which is almost exactly what you asked for, and very close to your working code. The main difference is that the missing values are their own category.

The key lines are:

- Use `pctlevel=group`
- Use `missing`

Here is the code:

```
proc sgplot data = test 
    pctlevel = group
;
    vbar category / 
        stat       = percent
        group      = test_location 
        grouporder = data
        missing
        seglabel
    ;
    keylegend / 
        title    = "Testing Location" 
        position = bottom
    ;
quit;
```

I get:

[image]